# Getting a value from a char array

Tags: c, arrays, input, char

I have written a function below to take a `char` array and manipulate its values (namely, convert the char to an int if it is a number). However, I have a question with how the char array is managed. When I look at `input[i]`, it is the correct value (the value that was placed in the array. However, `&input[i]` gives a capital letter, and I don't know why it does that. For example, if I enter "11" and trace the variables, I might get the following result:

```
input[0] is 1
&input[0] is D
input[1] is 1
&input[1] is E
```

On to my code, if I try to use `input[i]`, I get the error of "passing argument makes pointer from integer without cast". If I use `&input[i]`, the code compiles but I get the wrong result. What's going on with this, and how do I access the value I'm trying to get?

Below is my code:

```
void myFunction(char *input) {
    Queue* numberQueue = queue_new();
    Queue* opQueue = queue_new();
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < strlen(input); j++) {
        printf("input[%d] is %c\n", i, input[i]);
        printf("&input[%d] is %c\n", i, &input[i]);

        int number = (int)input[i];

        /* queue_push_tail(queue, data) */
        queue_push_tail(numQueue, number);            /* ERROR */

        /* rest of code omitted */

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: what do you think `&input[i]` is?

Comment: Doesn't the `&` mean it's a reference to where the variable is in memory? I don't completely understand why that would work, but the normal variable doesn't.

Comment: @anoneponymous you are printing an address and converting it to a %c so basically anything could appear.

Comment: @anoneponymous Not really. It is an operator that gives you the *address* of the operand.

Comment: Oh, I understand a bit more clearly. So I am converting the address of `input[i]` to a character, rather than the value stored at `input[i]`. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, you are telling `printf` that you will pass it a `char`, but you pass it an address. Because the types don't match, `printf` can do whatever it likes. Your program has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that you want to push each digit in the `input` character string into `queue_push_tail`, as an **integer value** then you want your loop to do something like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < strlen(input); j++) {

    if ( input[j] >= '0' && input[j] <= '9')
    {
        number = input[j] - '0';

        /* queue_push_tail(queue, data) */
        queue_push_tail(numQueue, number);            /* ERROR - FIXED*/

        /* rest of code omitted */
    }
}
```

Recall, ASCII characters are themselves unsigned integers. You simply need to adjust the value for each character by subtracting the value of ASCII `'0'`. If you need to collect all numbers from the string into a single number (e.g. ac7f9gh3 => `793`) then simply store the values unadjusted in a temp string, and then call `atoi (temp)`.